# Python re.search() not returning anything

Tags: python, regex

Here is my code snippet:

```
elif outputLn.startswith ('GET'):
            regex = '(.*)Packages(Id=\'' + self.m_name + '(.*))'
            nugetOutput.append(re.search(regex, outputLn).group().replace('\n', ''))
```

So my outputLn is

```
"GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Prism.PubSubEvents',Version='1.0.0')\r\n"
```

And my regex is this:

```
(.*)Packages(Id='Prism.PubSubEvents(.*))
```

What i want is that if the input line matches this pattern to put it in the arrary (but I have to take the \n off as well). Why is this not working? Currently it is returning None.

Comment: What is the value of `self.m_name`?

Comment: Prism.PubSubEvents (in unicode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to escape the "middle" set of parentheses:

```
(.*)Packages\(Id='Prism.PubSubEvents(.*)\)
            ^ escape this               ^ and this
```